# Directus - Example hook for creating or update an item in another collection

Tags: php, directus

I'm building a mobile app that has a list view which displays links to articles. The app's content is powered by Directus.

The list view has

```
title
description (200 characters, no HTML)
image
```

An article has

```
title
content (html)
image
```

To save the size of API requests, I'm storing the list view data in a collection called `articles_list` and articles in a collection called `articles`.

To keep Directus intuitive for the author, I need Directus to automatically create/update/delete an item in the `articles_list` collection for when an item is created/updated/deleted in the `articles` collection.

Both collections store basically the same data except that `articles_list` has `description` instead of `content`. The `description` field has the first 200 characters of `content` after the HTML tags have been removed.

I've had a look at the hooks documentation but I'm not sure how to create a new item in a different collection (`articles_list`). What's the best way of using an external library such as ezyang/htmlpurifier? How do I go about debugging my hook?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm still learning to understand how Directus works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend creating one collection that has 4 fields:

```
title
excerpt (/ description)
content (html)
image
```

You can then use the `fields` parameter to only request the `title` and `excerpt` on your overview pages to save some bandwidth / latency:

`/items/articles?fields=title,excerpt`

It also saves you the hassle of having to keep two collections in sync, and it prevents having to store duplicate data

Comment: Thank you! But I would still need to remove the HTML tags and trim for excerpt which would need HTML purifier? Also could you answer the best way to debug a hook?

Comment: No, I would recommend having a separate text-area next to the main HTML for the excerpt. That way you don't have to do any HTML clean ups (and you get the added bonus of being able to tweak the excerpt separately from the html.

Comment: Debugging a hook is the same as debugging any other piece of PHP. I'm not a PHP developer myself, but I tend to var_dump() and die() my way to victory 

Comment: I thought it would be easier for the author if the excerpt was automatically taken from the content. But maybe too much for me to implement at this stage. I thought that might be the best way and I do something similar when I use Laravel but since hooks happen in the background, they don't normally output to the browser window or do they?

Answer (score 0):

This is an example for debug inside a hook 
[image]

And your question is here, if you want to change another collection field from hook the better way is to use ZendDB [Example filter hook to update item with related field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55347047/example-filter-hook-to-update-item-with-related-field)